How do you cite a published book that is a translation of an unpublished diary?
A book (ISBN: 0837156807) with the title 'The Diaries of Tchaikovsky' contains English translation of the un-published personal diaries of the Russian composer - how should this book be cited using APA7?
There are many guides on how to cite translated works, but they all presume that the source was its own published work e.g.

Tchaikovsky, P. (1973). The Diaries of Tchaikovsky (W. Lakond, Trans.). Greenwood Press. (Original work published ????). ISBN 0-8371-5680-7.

To say "Original work published" is not correct, because these are personal diaries that were never published. Does it remain correct to include the translation publishing date next to Tchaikovsky's name, given that his writings were not published? It seems misleading.
What is the correct way to reference, with the APA7 system, a published book that is a translation of an unpublished work, like a diary?

When there is no specific form listed in the style book that you are using, I think you are justified in improvising. So, I'd just change "published" to "written".

In this particular case it seems that the original version may have been published in 1923.
